# Insert smallint to a time pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I'm doing a python script with pyodbc, so now I'm having this trouble, the script gets some data from one table, one of that data is a smaillint type and its suppouse to be a time so this script insert this info to another table but when it insert this field its wrong:

Something like:

Select date (SMALLINT):

By the way, I only use intervals of 30min:

```
0
30
130
200
230
1530
1600
```

And when its inserted to a time type table its:

```
00:00:00
00:00:30
00:01:30
00:02:00
00:02:30
00:15:30
00:16:00
```

And its suppouse to be

```
    00:00:00
    00:30:00
    01:30:00
    02:00:00
    02:30:00
    15:30:00
    16:00:00
```

This is my code:

```
        # ------------------------------------
        # Creando Registro de Inicio ****hagent****
        # ------------------------------------

        finicio = datetime.datetime.now()
        valores = (finicio_script, fichero, finicio, ip, ipDestino[cont], tablas[0])
        #print valores #Prueba de valores a insertar
        #Se comienza con la creacion de registro en BDD local
        print "Realizando creacion de Log de Registro"
        cadenaSQL = (
                "INSERT INTO log_scripts_CMS(id_proceso, fichero, fecha_hora_inicio, srv_origen, "
                "srv_destino, tipo_script) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                )
        #print cadenaSQL #Prueba de query
        registro_cursor.execute(cadenaSQL, valores)
        #Se empieza con la insercion de datos a las bdd
        print "Insertando datos a", ipDestino[cont]+ " tabla: " + tablas [0]

        cadenaSQL = (
        "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+tablas[0]+"(row_date, **starttime_utc**, intrvl, acd, skill, extension, "
        "logid, loc_id, rsv_level, i_stafftime, ti_stafftime, i_availtime, ti_availtime, i_acdtime, i_acwtime, "
        "i_acwouttime, i_acwintime, ti_auxtime, i_auxouttime, i_auxintime, i_othertime, acwincalls, acwintime, "
        "auxincalls, auxintime, acwoutcalls, acwouttime, acwoutoffcalls, acwoutofftime, acwoutadjcalls, "
        "auxoutcalls, auxouttime, auxoutoffcalls, auxoutofftime, auxoutadjcalls, event1, event2, event3, "
        "event4, event5, event6, event7, event8, event9, assists, acdcalls, acdtime, acwtime, o_acdcalls, "
        "o_acdtime, o_acwtime, da_acdcalls, da_anstime, da_abncalls, da_abntime, holdcalls, holdtime, holdabncalls, "
        "transferred, conference, abncalls, abntime, i_ringtime, i_da_acdtime, i_da_acwtime, da_acdtime, da_acwtime, "
        "da_othercalls, da_othertime, ringcalls, ringtime, ansringtime, ti_othertime, da_acwincalls, da_acwintime, "
        "da_acwocalls, da_acwotime, da_acwoadjcalls, da_acwooffcalls, da_acwoofftime, noansredir, incomplete, "
        "acdauxoutcalls, i_acdaux_outtime, i_acdauxintime, i_acdothertime, phantomabns, i_auxtime, holdacdtime, "
        "da_release, acd_release, ti_auxtime0, ti_auxtime1, ti_auxtime2, ti_auxtime3, ti_auxtime4, ti_auxtime5, "
        "ti_auxtime6, ti_auxtime7, ti_auxtime8, ti_auxtime9, acdcalls_r1, acdcalls_r2, i_otherstbytime, i_auxstbytime"
        ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
        ",?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
        "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
        )
        #print  (cadenaSQL) #Comprobaacion de query
        #Se insertan datos en bdd local
        if cuenta_hagent != 0:
            crsr.executemany(cadenaSQL, hagent)
            print "Listo!"
        else:
            print "No hay datos por insertar"
```

**EDIT:**

This how I got the data from another table to save them in another database:

```
# ------------------------------------
    # Obtencion de datos de la tabla hagent
    # ------------------------------------

    tablas_informix = ["hagent", "hsplit", "intradaytramo", "loginout"]
    #Se obtienen los datos.
    print "Recuperando datos de la tabla ", tablas_informix[0]
    #Se obtienen datos de la tabla hagent
    cadenaSQL = (
    "SELECT hagent.row_date AS FECHA, hagent.starttime AS starttime, hagent.intrvl AS intrvl, hagent.acd AS acd, hagent.split AS skill, "
    "hagent.extension, hagent.logid, hagent.loc_id, hagent.rsv_level, hagent.i_stafftime, hagent.ti_stafftime, hagent.i_availtime, "
    "hagent.ti_availtime, hagent.i_acdtime, hagent.i_acwtime, hagent.i_acwouttime, hagent.i_acwintime, hagent.ti_auxtime, hagent.i_auxouttime, "
    "hagent.i_auxintime, hagent.i_othertime, hagent.acwincalls, hagent.acwintime, hagent.auxincalls, hagent.auxintime, hagent.acwoutcalls, "
    "hagent.acwouttime, hagent.acwoutoffcalls, hagent.acwoutofftime, hagent.acwoutadjcalls, hagent.auxoutcalls, hagent.auxouttime, "
    "hagent.auxoutoffcalls, hagent.auxoutofftime, hagent.auxoutadjcalls, hagent.event1, hagent.event2, hagent.event3, hagent.event4, "
    "hagent.event5, hagent.event6, hagent.event7, hagent.event8, hagent.event9, hagent.assists, hagent.acdcalls, hagent.acdtime, "
    "hagent.acwtime, hagent.o_acdcalls, hagent.o_acdtime, hagent.o_acwtime, hagent.da_acdcalls, hagent.da_anstime, hagent.da_abncalls, "
    "hagent.da_abntime, hagent.holdcalls, hagent.holdtime, hagent.holdabncalls, hagent.transferred, hagent.conference, hagent.abncalls, "
    "hagent.abntime, hagent.i_ringtime, hagent.i_da_acdtime, hagent.i_da_acwtime, hagent.da_acdtime, hagent.da_acwtime, hagent.da_othercalls, "
    "hagent.da_othertime, hagent.ringcalls, hagent.ringtime, hagent.ansringtime, hagent.ti_othertime, hagent.da_acwincalls, hagent.da_acwintime, "
    "hagent.da_acwocalls, hagent.da_acwotime, hagent.da_acwoadjcalls, hagent.da_acwooffcalls, hagent.da_acwoofftime, hagent.noansredir, "
    "hagent.incomplete, hagent.acdauxoutcalls, hagent.i_acdaux_outtime, hagent.i_acdauxintime, hagent.i_acdothertime, hagent.phantomabns, "
    "hagent.i_auxtime, hagent.holdacdtime, hagent.da_release, hagent.acd_release, hagent.ti_auxtime0, hagent.ti_auxtime1, hagent.ti_auxtime2, "
    "hagent.ti_auxtime3, hagent.ti_auxtime4, hagent.ti_auxtime5, hagent.ti_auxtime6, hagent.ti_auxtime7, hagent.ti_auxtime8, hagent.ti_auxtime9, "
    "hagent.acdcalls_r1, hagent.acdcalls_r2, hagent.i_otherstbytime, hagent.i_auxstbytime FROM root.hagent "
    "WHERE(hagent.row_date = '"+fecha_consulta+"') AND hagent.acd = '"+str(acd[0])+"' AND hagent.split IN ("+condicionIn+") AND starttime = "+hora_query+" "
    "ORDER BY starttime;"
    )
    #Se inicializa cursor.
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cadenaSQL)
    hagent = []
    hagent = cursor.fetchall()
    print "Listo!"
    #print cadenaSQL
    cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain the mapping from SMALLINT to TIME. For example, if `130` corresponds to `13:00:00` then what does `131` correspond to?

Comment: By the way, when I use pyodbc to insert the integer value `130` into a `TIME` column I get `00:01:30`, not `00:13:00`.

Comment: Check your work. The example results you show are inconsistent. If `200` produces `00:02:00` and `230` produces `00:02:30` then I would expect `130` to produce `00:01:30` (as I got), not `00:13:00`.

Comment: @GordThompson Srry Its correct thats the result, that was my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply multiply the SMALLINT value by 100. This works for me:

```python
x = 130
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO table1 (timecol) VALUES (?)", x * 100)
# value inserted is 01:30:00
```

Comment: But, this is the hard part for me maybe, because the script extract the data for another table by another cursor keeping all in one list.

Comment: Well, you could change the SELECT query to retrieve `smallint_time * 100 AS modified_smallint_time` instead of just retrieving `smallint_time` in its raw form.